# Using app resw file from background task

Tags: c#, resources, windows-8, microsoft-metro, background-process

I'm working on a Modern UI app and i'm currently trying to access my app's resources file (Resources.resw) from a backgroundtask. Both are in different projects in the same solution.
I tried that way :

```
ResourceLoader resources = new ResourceLoader("MyApp/Resources");
```

But i've got an arror as it can't get to the resources map.

Is there a specific way to do that ?

Comment: I tried the other way around : putting the resw file in a Common project referenced by both my app and my backgroundtask but i can't make that work either.

Comment: I am trying to do the same and am stuck too, see my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363214/pass-parameters-to-ibackgroundtask

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone comes across this.

In UWP, it seems that you don't have to do anything special to make this work. If the `.resw` files are included in the main UWP project, you can use the resource loader to retrieve them even from the background task assembly. For a resource string called *LiveNotifications-ItemComplete*, it would be the following:

`var resource = new ResourceLoader().GetString("LiveNotifications-ItemCompleted");`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use just the name of the resource file. If the name is MyResources.resw, then use:

```
ResourceLoader resources = new ResourceLoader("MyResources");
```

Comment: My file is Resources.resw and i tried every single variation **Resources**, **MyCommonProject/Resources**, **MyCommonProject** ... even when not specifying a filename it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Though it's an old post, I thought I'd post my findings as none of the suggestions in this post worked for me when I tried to use it with my background task in my UWP app for Windows 10.

The way I achieved it was as follows:

```
string str = ResourceLoader.GetForViewIndependentUse("Resources").
             GetString("MyLocalizedKey");
```

Where

- `"Resources"` is the name of the `.resw` file in your "App\String\en-US" or "App\Strings\fr-FR" for example.

and

- `"MyLocalizedKey"` is the actual key of the value you want to obtain from the resource file.

Now remember that if you use this method, you will have to put all the strings of your `BackgroundTask` in the main application.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is just not possible. Resw can probably only be accessed when within the store app project. At least that is my observation and i have tried everything to my knowledge.

I can however offer a solution if you want to pass parameters to your background task. Add the resw file to your Windows Store App project. When you register your background task, write your settings (or whatever it is you need to pass over to the background task) to the local settings of your device. Then, from your background task read the same setting from your local settings.

Its not perfect but it works well. I am sorry if this does not help your.