# Pass parameters to IBackgroundTask

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am implementing a windows store application for windows rt. It uses a backgroundtask to update its tile. I want to be able to configure the backgroundtask and the application to use the same urls when performing work, so i want to use a unified or centralized configuration. Right now i am using some *.resw files to configure certain aspects in my Windows Store application. How can i pass this configuration to the background task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weirdly enough i answered my own question in a different thread

[Using app resw file from background task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233962/using-app-resw-file-from-background-task?lq=1)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is using  `ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings` 
Here is an example of wrapper which I use in my app:

```
  public class SettingsService
    {

        private readonly ApplicationDataContainer _container;

        public SettingsService()
        {
            var localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

            if (!localSettings.Containers.ContainsKey("AppSettings"))
            {
                _container = localSettings.CreateContainer("AppSettings", ApplicationDataCreateDisposition.Always);
            }
            else
            {
                _container = localSettings.Containers["AppSettings"];
            }
        }

     private T GetValue<T>(string key, T @default)
        {

            if (_container.Values.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                return (T)_container.Values[key];
            }

            return @default;
        }

        private void SetValue(string key, object value)
        {
            if (!_container.Values.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                _container.Values.Add(key, value);
            }
            else
            {
                _container.Values[key] = value;
            }

        }

       //Any setting
   public bool IsFirstLaunch
    {
        get { return GetValue("IsFirstLaunch", true); }
        set { SetValue("IsFirstLaunch", value); }
    }
}
```